# Represent a list in matrix format

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match

I have an Excel file with these columns and values:

[image: sheet11]

[image]
<-To be:

I can easily insert a PivotTable and make the array but I need a formula that will add an `x` if `a` is present in `1`, `3`, `4`, `5` and the same for `b`: if is present in `1` add an `x`, if is present in `5` add an `x` etc.

Is it something that can be done using an INDEX/MATCH or should a VB script be used instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the layout from your images, you can enter this formula in cell B2 of the report sheet:

```
=REPT("x",0<COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,B$1,Sheet1!$B:$B,$A2))
```

...and then copy over and down as far as needed.

Note: this assumes that the source list is on Sheet1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((B$1=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)*($A2=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10)),"x","")
```